# assistance with html and css

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a loading page for my website but there is a white line along the top and one down the left side. Could someone please help me with this,
Thanks.

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>

        html {
            cursor: none;
        }

        .container {
            background-color: black;
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 1000;
        }

        p {
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0; bottom:0; left: 0; right:0;
            font-family: courier;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        img {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0; bottom:0; left: 0; right:0;
            margin: auto;
        }       

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
            <img src="progress.gif">
            <p> Loading... Please wait </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the default margin, you can add

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

to your css.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :)